# T-SQL Conceptual trigger issue

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am placing a trigger on a table in a vendor's software (on our machine of course) that will create a record of checks written in a specific format for our bank (because of the type of business we are in, we need up to the minute reporting on checks written for fraud management).  I've already written a robust application which does the job, however we are very apprehensive about any impact to the main software. For example, if *anything* goes wrong in the trigger, the whole application insert process (with multiple files) goes south, and we cannot afford to mess up production with a side application.

So we're going to write this check tracking record out with minimal data and handle it in a way removed from the application.

The question: is there a way to insure that even if our basically blank record cannot write that the INSERT in our vendor's software still goes on no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

I always find the most stable operations are set based:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT SomeValue
FROM Inserted
WHERE [logic here]
```

If it fails the logic it will just insert zero rows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- don't use a trigger.

Instead of, say:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckSpy ON checks 
FOR AFTER INSERT AS 
INSERT INTO dbo.Spy(CheckID) 
SELECT CheckID
FROM INSERTED 
WHERE type="Fraud"
```

You can just write a stored procedure that pulls the inserted records AFTER they have been written.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Spy(CheckID, ...)
SELECT C.CheckID, ... 
FROM dbo.CheckID  as I 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Checks as C
  ON I.CheckID = C.CheckID
WHERE I.checkID IS NULL 
  AND I.Type = 'Fraud'
```

Comment: Tell me more about this... I am using an AFTER trigger as it is (should have mentioned that, sorry). If my trigger fails to write out to my database on the side, will anything from the user's perspective fail? In this case, I'm happy with getting no feedback and finding it in our SSIS after-the-fact monitoring.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. If I write a stored procedure instead of a trigger and I have no access to the vendor's software, how do I check it after the fact? In a script running elsewhere throughout the day (which we are already doing in SSIS, so it's not to be ruled out)

Comment: You can't make a trigger without MODIFY access to the database; if yuo have that, you can write a stored procedure, or a SQL statement in a separate SSIS job, to get the checks.  My point is, if you want to absolutely avoid the chance of your trigger killing an INSERT, don't use to a trigger.  (Is it likely? No.  But it is possible.)

Comment: We have modify access, but you speak wise words. We're scaling back on the trigger end and using transaction logic to help protect the application table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `Instead of Insert Trigger` , which validates any data before it gets inserted. Do checks for data validation and once satisfied do the insert than, otherwise if it fails the validation checks just send an user friendly error message back, telling end users how to fix the problem and attempt again.

Afterall you dont want your customers to just walk away just because your trigger doesnt like it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Trigger_Name
ON Table_Name
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY 

            /*DO your data validation checks here*/

              IF (/*check No 1*/)
               BEGIN
                 RAISERROR('Send this message to user to guide what to do', 16, 1)
               END

              IF (/*check No 2*/)
               BEGIN
                 RAISERROR('Send this message to user to guide what to do', 16, 1)
               END

   /*Once Validation is done and you are happy to continue with the transaction*/

   BEGIN TRANSACTION
     INSERT /* Insert data what ever you want*/

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   END TRY


   BEGIN CATCH
     /*If something has gone wrong During Validation of Data Insert*/

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        /*DO other stuff here in case of an error or validation faliure */


   END CATCH

END
```

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be anything for us to check, it's simply a real-time data gathering. Perhaps it's my paranoia (or t-sql inexperience) that if something is wrong with the connection between databases or random space dust that the trigger could fail. I just don't want it to gum up the works.

Comment: @user2820556 in this trigger anything done outside of the `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT TRANSATION` will not effect the data on your disk. In this case when you do not have any checks  Just simply use a Stored Procedure to the insert the data and wrap you `INSERT STATEMENT` insdie a `Explicit TRANSACTION` , Explicit TRANSACTION allow you to have the control when data is actually saved to the disk, if anything goes wrong in the middle of a transaction before you commit it the whole operation is rolled back. and your data is not left in Half-done state.

Comment: @user2820556 I would suggest to create a stored Procedure with pretty much similar definition, if you dont want any checks dont do it use, `Try and Catch` blocks and also `Explicit TRANSACTIONS`. and you are in safe land :)

Comment: Thanks, I will experiment with this!

Comment: Who has downvoted it and why please would like to hear your comments ??